# Find Position of Third Vertex of a Two Triangles with Constant Base and Known Opposite Angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to find the rectangular coordinates of the third vertex of two connected triangles with a constant base and known opposite angles. It's for a positioning system and I need help working out the position of the third vertex if the base of each is constant and I can measure the two opposite angles. I'm only concerned with positions in the positive **y** region. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi4M8.png)
[image]

Comment: Hint: the locus of a point with a constant angle against two fixed points is an arc of circle (actually, the union of two such symmetric arcs). Determine the two circles for angles $\theta, \phi$ then the third vertex will be the other point(s) of intersection of those circles.

Comment: Turns out, MATLAB Symbolic Toolbox finds a closed-form solution but it's horrendously long and complicated: 318 characters for $r$ and 394 for $\alpha$. A Mathematica expert might be able to do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following dxiv’s hint, it’s also possible to do this without explicitly constructing the two circles.

[image: diagram]

Observe that the green circle defined by the origin, the point $P_1=(s,0)$ and the angle $\phi$ intersects the $y$-axis at the origin and $(0,s\cot\phi)$, so its center is at $C_1=\frac12(s,s\cot\phi)$. Similarly, the center of the blue circle is at $C_2=\frac12(-s,s\cot\theta)$. The point $Q$ you’re looking for is the reflection of the origin in the line through these two circle centers. This reflection is easy to compute. If the equation of the line $\overline{C_1C_2}$ is $ax+by+c=0$, then $Q$ is the point along the line $\lambda(a,b)$ such that its signed distance from $\overline{C_1C_2}$ is the negation of that line’s distance from the origin, i.e., $${-c-\lambda(a^2+b^2)\over\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}={c\over\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ so $\lambda =-{2c\over a^2+b^2}$ and $Q=\left(-{2ac\over a^2+b^2},-{2bc\over a^2+b^2}\right)$. Notice that there’s a third circle that you can work with as well, the black one defined by $P_1$ and $P_2$ and angle $\phi+\theta$, but the reflection in the center line is easiest to compute with the blue and green circles.

Working through this with the line $\overline{C_1C_2}$ results in $$Q=\left({s\,(\cot^2\theta-\cot^2\phi)\over4+(\cot\theta-\cot\phi)^2},{2s\,(\cot\theta+\cot\phi)\over4+(\cot\theta-\cot\phi)^2}\right)$$ or equivalently $$\left({s\,(\cos2\theta-\cos2\phi)\over3-2\cos2\theta-2\cos2\phi+\cos2(\theta+\phi)},{4s\sin\theta\sin\phi\sin(\theta+\phi)\over3-2\cos2\theta-2\cos2\phi+\cos2(\theta+\phi)}\right).$$ This last form has some geometric appeal because all three angles appear in it and the denominator involves the angles at the three circle centers.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is a closed form solution to this problem. The simplest equations I've found are:
$$
r \sin(\theta) = s \sin(\alpha-\theta) \\
r \sin(\phi) = s \sin(\alpha+\phi)
$$
where $x=r\cos(\alpha)$ and $y=r\sin(\alpha)$. MATLAB's `fsolve` function solves these two non-linear equations for $r$ and $\alpha$ for the few cases I tried. The following equations might be helpful for testing purposes
$$
\theta = \tan^{-1}{x+s \over y} - \tan^{-1}{x \over y} \\
\phi   = \tan^{-1}{x \over y} - \tan^{-1}{x-s \over y}
$$ 
but they don't work nearly as well with `fsolve`.

If you have a control problem where $\theta$ and $\phi$ change little between step $i$ and $i+1$, then you can probably find a fast way (e.g. Newton's method) to find $x_{i+1}$ and $y_{i+1}$ using $x_i$ and $y_i$ as a starting point.